# How create txt file with dynamic name VB

Tags: vb.net

I have loop,it creates txt file for each tabPage that i have created.Now every loop it just replace old "sml.txt" but i want to create sml1.txt,sml2.txt,sml3.txt ......

```
Dim FileWriter As StreamWriter
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("E:\CEE")
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("E:\CEE\smlouvy")


        For i = 1 To tabpagelist.LongCount
            FileWriter = New StreamWriter("E:\CEE\smlouvy\sml.txt", False) ----
       --Here i want every loop create new txt (sml & counter)
                For x = 0 To tabControls(tabpagelist(i)).LongCount - 1
                    FileWriter.WriteLine(tabControls(tabpagelist(i))(x).Name & "|" & tabControls(tabpagelist(i))(x).Text)
                Next
                FileWriter.Flush()
                FileWriter.Close()
            Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a plus sign at the end of the file name:

```
Dim FileWriter As StreamWriter
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("E:\CEE")
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("E:\CEE\smlouvy")
For i = 1 To tabpagelist.LongCount
 FileWriter = New StreamWriter("E:\CEE\smlouvy\sml.txt" + i.toString, False)
 For x = 0 To tabControls(tabpagelist(i)).LongCount - 1
  FileWriter.WriteLine(tabControls(tabpagelist(i))(x).Name & "|" &
  tabControls(tabpagelist(i))(x).Text)
 Next
 FileWriter.Flush()
 FileWriter.Close()
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
For i = 1 To tabpagelist.LongCount

    'Here i want every loop create new txt (sml & counter)
    Dim filename As String = String.Format("E:\CEE\smlouvy\sml{0}.txt", i)
    FileWriter = New StreamWriter(filename, False) ---

    For x = 0 To tabControls(tabpagelist(i)).LongCount - 1

        FileWriter.WriteLine(tabControls(tabpagelist(i))(x).Name & "|" & tabControls(tabpagelist(i))(x).Text)
    Next
    FileWriter.Flush()
    FileWriter.Close()

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Path.Combine` to create your directories.

`System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory` creates all required subdirectories, so you don´t have to call it twice.

Use `Using ... End Using` to ensure proper closing and disposing of the stream.

```
        Dim basePath As String = Path.Combine("E:\CEE", "smlouvy")
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath)
            For i = 1 To tabpagelist.LongCount
                Dim txtPath = Path.Combine(basePath, String.Concat("sml", i, ".txt"))
                Using FileWriter = New StreamWriter(txtPath, False)
                    For x = 0 To tabControls(tabpagelist(i)).LongCount - 1
                        FileWriter.WriteLine(tabControls(tabpagelist(i))(x).Name & "|" & tabControls(tabpagelist(i))(x).Text)
                    Next
                End Using
            Next
```